# How to remove this window sash?

Tags: windows

I have double hung windows with top sash falling down when unlocking. I figured I’d prob need replacement on the channel balance, but I’m not sure how to take the sash out of the frame. All I can find online is the ones with latches, which my sash doesn’t have. Here are the pictures [image: top corner of sash]

[image: the center of the two windows]

As you can see, it has two double-hung side by side, and the center seems to have been painted over. Im wondering if I need to cut open the center? The make of the window is PRIMECEL but cannot find any information online. The place is built in 2001 and I believe the windows have never been replaced.

Comment: Based on a couple articles that I have found, the manufacturer of the PrimeCel brand windows may likely be MIWD. You may be able to learn how to remove and/or fix your sash by contacting MIWD's Service dept. or nearby Dealer and get assistance from them. However, PrimeCel. might be a discontinued series and may experience issues locating or ordering a replacement balance. Best of luck!  

Link 1 - https://www.hbsdealer.com/news/mi-windows-and-doors-faces-class-action-suit/  
Link 2 - https://www.classactionrebates.com/settlements/mi-windows/  
Link 3 - https://miwindows.com/

Comment: Most likely the  side pieces can be removed from the window frame, allowing the sash to be removed. It could be screwed or they could even be flexibly "popped" into place.